# Positive integer to rational number that is not injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

What is an example of a function from positive integers to rational numbers that is not injective? 
If this was all integers it would be easy. The only thing I can think of is if you use ceilings but I don't think that is what it's looking for.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would you edit the title so it is not vauge, muddled and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you take $f(n)=1$ for each $n\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Hosep If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I would love to, but it says I can't because my reputation is not high enough.